# AWS block device mapping to mount a snapshot while creating separate root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I want to create a new instance with root mounting from its AMI (sda1), while at the same creating a secondary volume (sda2) from a snapshot.

I am using the following block device mapping to add sda2:

```
[
    {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda2", 
        "Ebs": {
            "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
            "SnapshotId": "snap-0daafbeb9409cb652"
        }
    }
```

]

However, while an sda1 volume is created from the AMI, it appears that sda2 is mounted as root

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part 
xvdb    202:16   0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvdb1 202:17   0   8G  0 part /
```

What should be different to cause xvda1 (which links to sda1) to mount as root instead? I do not want to modify the AMI to do this, the starting point for this process is a stock Ubuntu image.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-c80b0aa2 ... --block-device-mappings file://mappings.json
```

Comment: `sudo e2label /dev/xvda1` and `sudo e2label /dev/xvdb1`.  Do they have the same label?

Comment: Cripes. They do, they were both created by AWS using the same process, the second is a snapshot of the first: `$ blkid
/dev/xvda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="45a25334-26a8-41f4-97bd-ee71af165ff2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/xvdb1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="45a25334-26a8-41f4-97bd-ee71af165ff2" TYPE="ext4"`

Comment: Looking for AWS magic to change labels...

Comment: [aws docs: booting from the wrong volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-booting-from-wrong-volume.html)

Comment: There ya go.  Make it an answer.  You may need to create a volume from the snapshot, clear the label, then make a new snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the volume labels of the partitions being mounted. In this specific case, both volumes have the same label, indicating they are the root partition, which is confusing the boot process.

The solution here is to clear the label of the volume that is not being mounted as the root filesystem.